# How to store logs in different log tables using log4j2 and slf4j?

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j2

My question is how to store logs in different tables using log4j2.I categorized logs in different ways means transaction logs, Exception logs and audit logs.I created three tables in Sqlserver-2008 like Transaction_log, Exception_log,and Audit_Logs. Currently all logs stored in Transaction_log Table only.Now i want store  all error logs  in Exception_log table and All Info logs store in Transaction_log table.How can i categorized using log4j2.xml configuration file and i am using slf4j with log4j2. If any one have idea please share with me.Before i am using log4j 1.x properties file for this development.in log4j1.x properties fie is:

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log4j.rootLogger =ALL,TXN, EXP,CONSOLE

    log4j.category.TransactionLog=INFO, TXN
    log4j.additivity.TransactionLog=false

    log4j.category.ExceptionLog=ERROR,EXP
    log4j.additivity.ExceptionLog=false

    #CONSOLE
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n



    #Transaction log config details

     log4j.appender.TXN=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
     log4j.appender.TXN.URL=jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERname;databaseName=******
     log4j.appender.TXN.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
     log4j.appender.TXN.user=*****
     log4j.appender.TXN.password=****
     log4j.appender.TXN.sql=INSERT INTO Transaction_Log(LoggedDate, MethodName, Level, ClassName, Message) VALUES (GETDATE(),'%M()',  '%-5p', '%C---%L','- %m%n' )

    #Exception log config details

    log4j.appender.EXP=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
    log4j.appender.EXP.URL=jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERname;databaseName=******
    # Set Database Driver
    log4j.appender.EXP.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    log4j.appender.EXP.user=****
    log4j.appender.EXP.password=*****
    log4j.appender.EXP.sql=INSERT INTO Exception_Log(LoggedDate, MethodName, Level, ClassName, Message) VALUES (GETDATE(),'%M()',  '%-5p', '%C---%L','- %m%n' )
```

now i need to log4j2.xml like this.

my log4j.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration status="OFF">
  <appenders>
  <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    <JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="Transaction_Log">
     <DataSource jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/TestDB" />
       <Column name="LoggedDate" isEventTimestamp="true" />
       <Column name="MethodName" pattern="%M()" />
      <Column name="level" pattern="%level" isUnicode="false"  />
      <Column name="ClassName" pattern="%logger" isUnicode="false"  />
      <Column name="message" pattern="%m%n" isUnicode="false"  />
    </JDBC>
  </appenders>

  <loggers>
  <Logger name="org.apache.log4j.xml" level="all"/>
    <root level="all">
      <appender-ref ref="databaseAppender"/>
           <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please show your log4j2.xml

Comment: first i am developed these logging using log4j 1.x

Comment: Docs are here: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#JDBCAppender

Comment: see my updated question I added my log4j2.xml

Answer (score 1):

The root logger can have multiple appender-refs, each with a different level. A quick example:

```
<JDBC name="allEventsDatabaseAppender" tableName="tracedebuginfowarn_LOG">
    <Filters>
        <!-- Now deny error and fatal messages -->
        <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
        <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY"   onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
    </Filters>
    <DataSource jndiName="java:/comp/env/jdbc/TestDB" />
    ...
</JDBC>
...
<Root level="all">
  <AppenderRef ref="errorOnlyDatabaseAppender" level="ERROR" />
  <AppenderRef ref="allEventsDatabaseAppender" level="TRACE" />
  <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
</Root>
...
```

Comment: if i am writing like this error logs stored in all tables.i want to store logs error logs store in different tables and all transaction and audit logs in different tables

Comment: You can filter out the error/fatal events by using a filter. This way the "allEventsDatabaseAppender" will receive trace/debug/info/warn but not error/fatal events. I updated my answer to show how.

Comment: thanks your answer helped.please tell me how to configure log4j2.xml file using slf4j api.currently i placed in classpath means inside src folder.i want put log4j.xml file in resource folder now how can i read this  using slf4j api.

Comment: I am having transaction level errors, warnings, info messages and also exception level having errors and warnings, and audit level errors, warnings,info messages then how can i configure this three tables.